# Uncaught exceptions not working

Tags: android, google-analytics

My app_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <!-- The apps Analytics Tracking Id -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-1</string>
    <!-- Percentage of events to include in reports -->
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>
    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <!-- catch and report uncaught exceptions from the app -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <!-- How long a session exists before giving up -->
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>
</resources>
```

global_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <!-- the Local LogLevel for Analytics -->
    <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
    <!-- how often the dispatcher should fire -->
    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">1</integer>
    <!-- Treat events as test events and don't send to google -->
    <bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>
    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <string name=".BaseActivity">Base Activity</string>
</resources>
```

Application.java

```
public class Application extends Application {
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-1";

    //Logging TAG
    private static final String TAG = "Application";

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = 
        new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, 
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, 
    }

    public Application() {
        super();
    }

    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? 
                                    analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? 
                                    analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                    : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

Activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Application app= (Application) getApplication();
        Tracker myTracker=app.getTracker(Application.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        myTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
        myTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true); //add this line
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).enableAutoActivityReports(app);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(true){
            new Integer("asdfas");
        }
}
```

I'm trying to report all uncaught exceptions to google analytics but it's not working. Anyone have an idea why my uncaught exceptions are not being sent to google analytics?

Thank in advance.

Comment: How long have you wait for the exceptions? It could take a day or two until the exceptions appear in the analytics.

Comment: Really? I've waited for 6 hours

Comment: Yes, from my experience.

Comment: I've just checked right now and i can see the exceptions. Do you have any experience with bugsense?

Comment: Good to hear that. No, I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exceptions report could take a day or two until they appear in the analytic console.